# output azure eventhub service using filebeat

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-eventhub, filebeat

Is that possible to use output as output.azure via file beat in the filebeat.yml file and input from a local file or we need Kafka as output to inject a logs to eventhub azure.

As far as I explored, only I can see kafka module as output  one for sending logs to Azure EventHub

And storage account is necessary for eventhub injection or not ??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We use filebeat with event hubs via kafka surface. In your filebeat.yaml you use normal kafka output pointing to the event hubs instance. Your config would be something like this:

```yaml
output.kafka:
  topic: ${event_hub_connect_topic}
  required_acks: 1
  client_id: filebeat
  version: '1.0.0'
  hosts:
    - ${event_hub_connect_hosts}
  username: "$ConnectionString"
  password: ${event_hub_connect_string}
  ssl.enabled: true
  compression: none
```

Note that you can use env vars in these settings. Since we use filebeat in k8s, we provide them through a secret.

As for the storage account, I believe you only need it if you want to use the capture feature of event hubs.